# How to use same jars folder across main and dependent library project during ant build in Android?

Tags: android, ant

I've got Android project that consist for one main project and two dependent library projects.

I want to setup ant to reuse external library folder across all three projects.

I've tried to put following line to ant.properties:
   jar.libs.dir=../libs

But it has no effect and still get errors that jar classes not founded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i put all jars inside project default libs folder. Android correctly merges duplicated libs from library projects.

PS: But this is still a pain if library project is located in separate repository.